# Find four different solutions to $\frac{dx}{dt}=\frac{3}{2}x^{\frac{1}{3}}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the differential equation $\frac{dx}{dt}=\frac{3}{2}x^{\frac{1}{3}}$. Find four different solutions to this differential equation, all defined on $\mathbb{R}$ and satisfying $x(0)=0$. Find an additional solution to this differential equation on $\mathbb{R}$ such that $x(0)=0$ and $x(10)=8$.

I have already found one solution being $x=t^{\frac{3}{2}}$. I am unsure how to go about finding the remaining solutions. Any strategies I can consider?

Comment: How do you know there are four solutions?

Answer (score 1):

The equation is autonomous, and you can freely shift it over $t$ (giving an infinity of solutions if a non-constant solution exists).

$x(t)=0$ is a trivial solution. Then

$$x^{-1/3}dx=\frac23dt\implies x^{2/3}=t+c\implies x=\pm(t+c)^{3/2},$$ which is valid for $t+c\ge0$.

The second condition gives

$$8^{2/3}=10+c$$ and $$c=-6.$$

> $$\begin{cases}x\le6\to0,\\x\ge6\to(t-6)^{3/2}.\end{cases}$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $x(t) = 0$ works for any $t$. The function $x(t) = (t-1)^{3/2}$ works for $t\geq 1$. Stitch them together.